# Sum of digits of ternary and novenary numbers

Tags: natural-numbers, ternary-expansion

When a natural number is represented as a ternary (base 3), the sum of the digits is 2007.  What are the maximal and minimal values of the sum of digits when it is represented as a novenary (base 9)?

*I have no clue.*

Comment: I would approach this by playing around with some numbers. Convert small numbers into base $3$ and then base $9$. Can you see any patterns?

Comment: You say you have no clue, but [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). You have lots of clues. What you don't know is how a **finished solution starts**, but that's entirely fine. That happens to everyone all the time. Don't let that stop you from **looking** for that solution.

Comment: I think I should assume that the ternary is D1D2D3...Dn where D1 to Dn are the digits, and the sum of them is 2007.   If I can find a way to represent the digits of the novenary by D1 to Dn, then I may have a chance.  But I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: I think I have found the pattern, which is to pair up digits of adjacent positions and convert each pair into a decimal number which will be a digit of the novenary.  But this is only a conjecture, how to give a rigorous math proof that this pattern can always be used for converting a ternary into a novenary?

Comment: Think about how a position system like ternary or decimal is defined (e.g. what does $112202$ in ternary actually _mean_?) Compare the description of ternary to the description of nonary. See how your "pairing up" actually works algebraically. There is your proof.

Answer (score 0):

So first we note that to convert from ternary to novenary we simply go from the least significant digit (or "trit") and pair them up and convert each pair into a novenary digit from ternary (I'll leave it to you to see why this is case)

So really we have a bunch of pairs $\in \{0,1,2\}^2$ such that all the numbers have a fixed sum (2007 in this case), and we want to maximise the sum of all the digits when we convert to base 9. So really we want to maximise the base 9 representation of every pair.

So to make the best use of the fixed sum, we need to only put non-zero values in the first element of the pair, as that corresponds to a higher value in base 9.

Interestingly from here (again I'll leave it to you to see why), it's completely irrelevant how we distribute the sum, as the base-9 sum is always the same. So let's just do it the obvious way and have $2007$ pairs all equal to $(1,0)$, so the maximal base-9 sum is $1*3*2007 = 6021$.

Comment: You said that the sum of the novenary digits is always 6021, I think I can prove that it's not ture.  Say the ternary is 1(01)...(01)(01) where we have 2006 pairs of (01), then the novenary will be 11...111111 where we have the 2007 digit '1' and the sum of the digits is 2007.

Comment: It's always the same when we add the restriction that all the digits that are second in a pair are zero ("interestingly *from here* [see previous paragraph]...")

Comment: Aha, I think I have accidentally found the minimal value.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't see that they wanted both. Yes yours is an example of one with minimal digit sum.

Comment: I really want to see a rigorous math proof of the pattern of relationships (pairing them up) between the ternary and novenary digits...